# Table overflow inside flex break parent width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like the table with more columns than it fits on the page to scroll horizontally. I have a page based on flex display. The code below works just as I would like until the comments code is restored. Suddenly the table is thrown beyond the page width and I can't figure out why and how it can be fixed. On the site I have even more nested levels of flexboxes, also the use of a comment as in the example below, unfortunately, is not an option. Any idea?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Why :(</title>
    <style>
     body{width: 600px; margin: 0 auto}
     .container{margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;}
     .flexbox{display: flex; flex-direction: row;}
     .full_size_column{flex: 0 0 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <!--
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="full_size_column">
    -->
          <div class="flexbox">
            <div class="full_size_column" style="overflow-x: auto">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                    <th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th><th>Points</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                    <td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                    <td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td><td>66</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Adam</td><td>Johnson</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                    <td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td><td>98</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
    <!--      
        </div>
      </div>
    -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[How it looks working and broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro0uK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your browser what happens if you have an x-overflow, just add in style "overflow:auto;" in your flexbox class.
Also flex-direction is row by default so no need to precise it. I tested your code with the comments restored and it works fine

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: good point, your solution works for me too, thanks a lot for your help